# Looks like a material problem, but I can't find anything to remove?

Tags: materials, faces, color

Really sorry as I'm a beginner and I don't know enough to characterize, or accurately search for what the problem may be. I've taken a picture of what I'm seeing, where it appears the faces have different textures, but nothing shows up under materials, and it's currently causing the solidify modifier to thicken differently along the edges and inside the areas.

I appreciate any help you all may give!
[image: Different Colored Regions No Materials]

Comment: Solidify modifier takes into account orientation of faces normals. Make sure to recalculate them in Edit mode

Comment: Thanks Mr Zak, I figured it out on a whim. I didn't know it colored them differently depending on the normals. Still a beginner :(

Answer (score 0):

When you solidify, make sure that ALL the faces are selected. Judging by your picture, it seems that you did not do this.  If I am incorrect, please upload your .blend file, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: actually, it's good to have posted a question like this.

Comment: (it keeps others from asking the same question ;))

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of my problem, I didn't understand that the color of the faces indicated the how the normals faced for the individual faces. It stumped me for quite awhile.

To give a solution to myself, you can go into Edit mode, use N to open the transform panel, scroll down till you see mesh display and open it. Select the cube icon to display the normals. You can then go and select all the faces you wish to change, press w for specials, and select to invert the normals.

Sorry to have posted a needless question.

Comment: As first he can try select all faces in edit mode by "A" and "Ctrl+N" for recalculate normals. Usually work fine and is much faster than selecting all inverted faces manually :-)